# How to swap elements in the same column of a 2d array in javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to swap the elements in an array whenever I come across a zero. I am able to swap going down, left, and right but when it comes to swapping up my function does not seem to work. The input and output stay the same and my code produces no error. Here is an example problem:

```
71 55 66 21
33 0  75 12
14 44 88 99
```

Here is my function for trying to swap element '44' and element '0':

```
if(puzzle[i][j] == 0 && direction == 'u' && i < rows - 1){
            var tmp = puzzle[i][j];
            puzzle[i][j] = puzzle[i+1][j];
            puzzle[i+1][j] = tmp;
            break;
        }
```

When I run this function in my program it outputs the same array. I've tried many different ways to solve this but none have given me the correct solution. Any guidance would help, Thanks

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). At first glance, your code swapping them seems fine provided that `puzzle[n]` gives you a row (which is fairly typical) rather than column. (Row-major or column-major in JavaScript is entirely up to you and your code, because JavaScript doesn't have multidimensional arrays; it has arrays of arrays.)

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/1ajtwcpL/ you need to show the rest of your code, that's where the error is.